# aspnetcore discovering razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a solution structured:

```
-Theme
  -Pages
   -_Host.cshtml
  -Services
-Core
  -Warmup.cs
-App
  -Program.cs
```

App project reference Theme project and Core project and start `Core.Warmup.StartAsync();`

the `StartAsync` Method Initialize and run a [Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihost?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) which means the [ApplicationName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.applicationname?view=aspnetcore-3.1) will be set to **Core**.

the issue is _Host.cshtml is not loaded and therefore : `Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area:  }.`

from microsoft [docs](http://from%20microsoft%20docs:):

> The applicationName setting needs to be set to the root assembly used for discovery. The root assembly used for discovery is normally the entry point assembly.

**NOTES :**

1- if i moved the warmup Initialize and running logic from Core to App razor pages (_Host.cshtml) is discovered.

2- i tried running the application with `dotnet run --applicationName` App but still does not work.

Comment: Hi sorry, I've read this a few times but what is the error/problem/question?

Comment: @RichardHousham `Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area:  }.` the _Host.cshtml file was not picked up